# DocuSign LoginInformation

Tags: docusignapi

I'm new to DocuSign API. I'm getting "com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code 404 with response Body: '' "

during execution using demo sandbox. I'm using docusign-java-client.
Please help me in this.

Comment: What API method are you using?  The client must establish a baseUrl which usually comes from a login_information request.  You may need to login first.

Comment: Can you post a code sample that shows how you are generating the API client? It's likely not being pointed at the correct environment.
Additionally, the LoginInformation method is for a legacy form of authentication that is generally discouraged. I'd recommend using the UserInfo methods documented here: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Java examples:

- [Authorization code grant](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant)
- [JWT grant](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-java-jwt)